# Map iterator undefined React.JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to render a list, but when I try and map over the list I can not access each individual element, because I ReferenceError saying that 'e' is undefined. Am I writing this correctly?

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         {console.log(Object.keys(this.props.emojis))} --> Returns the correct list
          Object.keys(this.props.emojis).map(e => (
              {console.log("EMOJI: ",e)}
              <Emoji emote={e} />
          ))
      </div>
    )
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write it like this, it will work:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
           {            
              Object.keys(this.props.emojis).map((e,i) => {
                 console.log("EMOJI: ",e);
                 return <Emoji key={i} emote={e}/>
              })
            }
      </div>
    )
 }
```

Changes:

- You are already inside a `map` function, so no need to use `{}` for `console.log`.
- You are using `()` with `map` function and inside `()` you are using 2 statement, that is not allowed with `()`, if you want to do some calculation always use `{}`, and return something inside it.

Suggestion: Always assign `key` whenever creating the ui items dynamically.

Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: I still get the e is not defined error and now the return statement doesnt allow webpack to build. I get an unexpected token error there :/

Comment: this part is ohk, want to see the other part of the code, could you show on pastebin or any other place ??

Comment: Yeah so I've just been testing out the code and I was mistaken. The above code only prevents the error but now the logs wont display. Here is my pastebin. Thanks http://pastebin.com/eauDrjGw

Comment: use the exact code, like this: `()=>{}`, this will definitely work i am sure about it :) in u r pastebin u used it like: ()=>(). change it by {} it will work. did one small change, use the updated code.

Comment: Thanks :D. I thought I initially did that but I guess I didn't. That was my initial approach, but I probably made some error somewhere. Cheers :D

Comment: thanks :), if u use it like this ()=>{} then u can write n nums of lines in {}, that the benefit of this, if u just want to return something then use it directly like this: (i)=> i+1;

Answer (score 1):

See if this work for you.

```
logging(e) {
    console.log("EMOJI: ", e);
}

render() {
   return (
     <div>
       Object.keys(this.props.emojis).map(e => (    
         this.logging(e);
         <Emoji emote={e} />
       ))
     </div>
   )
}
```

Comment: Yeah it does, cheers. Why do we use parentheses in the map instead of curly braces? I thought arrow functions require curly braces to signify an anon function

Comment: In my console maps work just fine with curly braces like x.map(e => asiofn), I dont know why there's a difference when we're using JSX

Comment: curly braces mean you are using state variable or props variable, double curly means you are ignoring all and treat it as normal JS.

Comment: hmm, 2 things. First, why does it then work for parentheses? You didn't mention it. Secondly if double curly braces work then why wouldn't Object.keys(this.props.emojis).map((e,i) => {{ console.log(e) }}) work? Thanks

Comment: This is React, all the curly braces is noticed as variable or JavaScript, but not the native JS, in native JS, always use curly braces for map, since it stand for block statement, or object declaration.

Comment: The second question is that, it should works if you are not using e, since inside the double curly braces, e is not defined, so you cannot console.log e there, it should throw you an exception for undefined object or variable

Comment: this link should help you understand more: https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/understanding-javascript-map/

Comment: Oh ok cheers. I've been testing the code and similar to what I mentioned in another comment, the errors disappear using your code but I dont actually get any logs :/

Comment: Sorry for late reply, i never online during weekends. The best way for you to console log the e, is to write a console.log function between render and return or outside the render functions, both should work, and call this function inside the loop, answer edited. remember to bind if it does not work